# Python list of lists assignment

Tags: python, list

One thing first: No, this is not a question about why

```
someThing = [[]] * 10
someThing[0] = 1
```

gives [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1].

My question is a bit more tricky:
I do the folling:

```
x, y, z = ([[]] for i in range(3))
```

Now I assign a value:

```
x[0] = 1   # This works fine
```

And now another one:

```
x[1] = 2   # This does not work anymore
```

It gives me an IndexError: list assignment index out of range.

How can I make this work? As you can see, I want an empty list that contains 3 other lists to which i can append values.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you look at what `x[0] = 1` actually does?  It replaces one of your nested lists with the number 1.  If you want to append values, you should use `append`, not item assignment.

Comment: yes you are right. but this is only an example. in my implementation, i do use append ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want an empty list that contains 3 other lists to which i can append
>   values.

Your problem correctly stated is: *"I want a list of three empty lists"* (something cannot be empty and contain things at the same time).

If you want that, why are you doing it in such a convoluted way? What's wrong with the straightforward approach:

```
empty_list = [[], [], []]
```

If you have such a list, when you do `empty_list[0] = 1`, what you end up with is:

```
empty_list = [1, [], []]
```

Instead, you should do `empty_list[0].append(1)`, which will give you:

```
empty_list = [[1], [], []]
```

If you want to create an arbitrary number of nested lists:

```
empty_list = []
for i in range(0, 15):
   empty_list.append([])
```

Comment: good question! the answer is simple: my 3 lists in one list were only an example. originally, i wanted to put 15 lists into a list. of course, your way is working, but it looks somewhat weird if i implement it that way. i just wanted to learn if there is an advanced way of doing this. but thanks ;)

Answer (score 3):

Since when

```
someThing = [] * 10
someThing[0] = 1
```

gives `[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]`? It's an index error (you can't assign at a nonexisting index), because actually `[]*10 == []`. Your code does exactly the same (I mean an index error). This line

```
x, y, z = ([[]] for i in range(3))
```

is short (or not) for

```
x, y, z = [[]], [[]], [[]]
```

so `x[1]` is an index error.

Comment: sry, you are right, i forgot brackets there. Yes i know the index does not exist, that is what the error message already told me. but how do i solve my problem?

Comment: @ZerO `I want an empty list that contains 3 other lists` I don't understand - it can be empty and contain something at the same time. If you want to append something to a list, then use `.append`. See Burhan's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this could work.

```
lists = [[] for i in range(3)]
```

The output would be:

```
[[],[],[]]
```

If you would like to access/add elements, you could:

```
lists[0].append(1)
lists[0].append(2)
lists[1].append('a')
lists[1].append('b')
```

The output would be:

```
[[1, 2], ['a', 'b'], []]
```

Comment: yes, this does work. but i need a multi-assignment ;)

Answer (score 0):

Comparing the output of:

```
for i in [[]] * 3:
    print id(i)
```

with:

```
for i in ([[]] for j in range(3)):
    print id(i)
```

may help answer your finding.

Comment: are you kidding me? Did you even read my question? I think i clearly showed that this is NOT the problem -.-

Comment: @ZerO: Did you even try the above code? I see no bearing on your question apart from the subtle but significant difference shown by the above. You have a 10 in your first example, and a 3 in your second. Why? If you already knew the difference between multiplication of lists versus generators, then `print i` and `print i[0]` and `print i[1]` as well and see why you are getting an `IndexError`. I am on SO thinking I like to learn and help, and I may be wrong in my answer.